# How can I build the latest tesseract 3.04 in windows 7 with visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, tesseract

I've found the pre-build 3.02 binary here: 
https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe&can=2&q=

I've found a example for building 3.03 in vs2013 here: 
https://github.com/tesseract4java/tesseract-vs2013

However, I have not been able to complete this sucessfully in Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Please post an error message

Answer (score 2):

I successfully build the latest tesseract version (3.05.00dev) by using build_tesseract.bat from https://github.com/peirick/leptonica.

Remember to put the updated language data (.traineddata) files into your tessdata directory afterwards. Can be found here https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata.

Comment: Thank you, I will have to give this a try. This was windows 7?

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis Did this work for you? If not, what did you do? I have been trying to make this work for days now.

Comment: i was never able to make it work with teh visual studio project. i used a prebuilt binary of an older version.

Comment: I might be missing something but did the build_tesseract.bat removed from leptonica repository ?